# Disable mouse scroll middle click event with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote the below code for disabling the scroll in the mouse while it is clicked.
but my code does not work an when I click with the scroll of my mouse it opens my link.

Here is my code :

```js
$('a').on('mousedown', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 2) {
    console.log('Disabled');
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#dontwanttoopen"> click here </a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `auxclick` in order to disable this feature. Replace your 'click' with 'auxclick', and add `e.preventDefault()`, it will work, tested in chrome and FF

```js
$('a').on('auxclick', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 2) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#dontwanttoopen"> click here </a>
```

Comment: how about firefox. there is not any codes that works in all browsers?

Comment: tested in FF 73 and chrome 73, I dont have access to safari and IE :)

Comment: thank u. :) can u tell me what is the meaning of : e.which === 2 ?

Comment: @inaz The `e.which` property returns which keyboard key or mouse button was pressed for the event.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `event.preventDefault()` to cancel a action

```js
document.onmousedown= function (e) {
    if( e.which == 2 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("middle button pressed, dont open"); 
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="#dontwanttoopen"> click here </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the code below, thanks :

```
<a href="#dontwanttoopen"  id="link_click">click here </a>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<script>
var el = document.getElementById('link_click');
el.onmousedown = mouse_down;


function mouse_down() {
alert('mouse_down() called');
return false;
}
</script>
```